# Не работают пакеты в atom

Tags: python, ide, atom

Временно поменял PyCharm на Atom. Проблема заключается в том, что у меня не запускается никакой из пакетов, которые я пытаюсь запустить...  Например, я скачал linter и он мне его не запускает, пишет, что мне его нужно засунуть в путь. Устанавливаю atom runner (запуск программы прямо в atom, чтобы не лезть в терминал), пишет:

```
Unable to find command: python
Are you sure PATH is configured correctly?
```

Загуглил. Засунул python в path. Сделал еще много каких махинаций, но результата не увидел. Скачал пакет script, который делает тоже самое - запускает программу в atom. Также не работает, гуглил и по этому поводу - где-то попробовал решение и не помогло, где-то просто не понял.
Скрин с ошибками:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS Изучаю linux не так давно, если это какая-то элементарная проблема не кидайтесь камнями, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил свою проблему :)

Для решения данной проблемы заходим в `Atom → Preferences → Open Config Folder (жмем на кнопку и открываем конфиг атома) → .atom/packages/script/lib/grammars/python.coffee` переходим в файл python.coffee и под 'Selection Based' и 'File Based' меняем 'python' на 'python3'